# How do you reference a single character in a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have this function with the goal of iterating over a 2D array and accessing a single character in the 2D array. But the `char** buffer` is becoming a point to a string from the 2D array and not a single character.

Here is my function:

```
bool screen_graph_interator(screen_graph_t* local, char** buffer, uint32_t* iteration, uint32_t start_x, uint32_t start_y, uint32_t width, uint32_t height) 
{
    // local variables
    int x, y;

    // TODO: Check for valide start_x, start_y, width, height inputs againsts local screen_graph

    // get index
    x = start_x + *iteration % width;
    y = start_y + *iteration / width;

    // if we're beyond domain and range we're done iterating
    if(*iteration > (width * height)-1) {
        *buffer = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    // get char ptr
    *buffer = &(local->field[x][y]);

    (*iteration)++;

    return true;
}
```

This line is what I believe contains my error `*buffer = &(local->field[x][y]);`

What I am seeing in my debugger is this: `new_char = 0x804a52c " XXXXXX "`

Where new_char is the `char*` I pass to `char** buffer`

It seems as though the value of new_char is a string am I right?

When I call `printf("%s\n\r", new_char);` it prints the entire string.

EDIT:

Here is `screen_graph_t` if you want to run my code

```
typedef struct screen_graph {
    char field[DISPLAY_ROWS][DISPLAY_COLS]; 
    bool expired;
} screen_graph_t;
```

EDIT:

Here is how I call screen_graph_interator:

```
bool screen_graph_changes(screen_graph_t* old_graph, screen_graph_t* new_graph) {
    // local variables
    char* old_char = NULL;
    char* new_char = NULL;
    uint32_t iteration = 0;         // the screen_graph iteration index
    uint32_t vt_string_index = 0;    // the position in the VT100 string, to be sent to putty session
    uint32_t skip_count = 0;        // the char count not changed

    while(screen_graph_interator(old_graph, &old_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS)) {
        iteration--;
        screen_graph_interator(new_graph, &new_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS);

        // check for character differences
        if(   *old_char != *new_char
           && *new_char != '\0') {

           // determine if we need a VT100 jump
           if(skip_count > 0) {

    ...
```

Comment: I don't see any variable "new_char" in your code. I also don't see how you invoke the function. My maigc 8-ball said you passed the address of a char* into the function, and a char* is naturally, a character array.

Comment: can you show how did you call the "screen_graph_interator" function.

Comment: You deleted your previous question about this code.  You need to look very hard at the order of the arguments `DISPLAY_COLS` and `DISPLAY_ROWS` to your `screen_graph_iterator()` function.  Unless the dimensions are the same (the screen is square), you access out of bounds of the `field` array in the structure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm handling that. Do you see something I dont? I mean I am not checking the input values. Also my previous error turns out to be the result of the compiler I have to use.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I deleted the previous edition of the code, with the instrumentation I'd added.  I would need to recreate the instrumentation.  I was asserting that the address returned by the function in `old_char`/`new_char` was in the range of addresses in `old_graph->field` or `new_graph->field`.

Comment: @NanonA I'm writing an ASCII Graphics Library. I'm demoing it using UART and PuTTY in a few weeks. But I plan to use it for other C projects.

Comment: @Jyby No, I mean what do you want this function to do?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that is interesting. I will have to try to analyze that somehow. I'm not seeing an issue with it now unless the function was provided with values that didnt make sense.

Comment: @NanonA this function should iterate over a 2D array starting from the top left and moving down each row. It will give me the address of the character in each location and the iteration or character count it is currently on. This function enables me to make selections into any screen graph in order to write and read from it.

Comment: You'd be OK if `DISPLAY_ROWS == DISPLAY_COLS`.  When they weren't equal, I was getting addresses out of bounds.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what you are trying to do but I will say this, `new_char` is a pointer if you write this `printf("%s\n", new_char)` it writes all the string until it sees a null-termination. You can write a single char like this `printf("%c\n" *new_char)`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I printed all the `x` and `y` it seems okay, "now"

Comment: @NanonA:  OK  — thanks.  Like I said, I found a problem in a previous question, now deleted (I probably could find it, but I'm not sure I can be bothered).  I've not compared this code with that code.

Comment: @NanonA: When I add assertions to the code, as in my answer, I get the assertions firing.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the code fragments above and converting them into the MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that should have been provided in the question and adding some basic assertions, you can end up with code like this:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { DISPLAY_ROWS = 24, DISPLAY_COLS = 50 };

typedef struct screen_graph
{
    char field[DISPLAY_ROWS][DISPLAY_COLS];
    bool expired;
} screen_graph_t;

static bool screen_graph_interator(screen_graph_t *local, char **buffer,
                uint32_t *iteration, uint32_t start_x, uint32_t start_y,
                uint32_t width, uint32_t height)
{
    int x = start_x + *iteration % width;
    int y = start_y + *iteration / width;

    if (*iteration > (width * height) - 1)
    {
        *buffer = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    *buffer = &(local->field[x][y]);

    assert(*buffer >= &local->field[0][0] &&
           *buffer <= &local->field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1]);

    (*iteration)++;

    return true;
}

static bool screen_graph_changes(screen_graph_t *old_graph, screen_graph_t *new_graph)
{
    char *old_char = NULL;
    char *new_char = NULL;
    uint32_t iteration = 0;

    while (screen_graph_interator(old_graph, &old_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS))
    {
        iteration--;
        screen_graph_interator(new_graph, &new_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS);
        assert(old_char >= &old_graph->field[0][0] &&
               old_char <= &old_graph->field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1]);
        assert(new_char >= &new_graph->field[0][0] &&
               new_char <= &new_graph->field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1]);

        if (*old_char != *new_char && *new_char != '\0')
        {
            printf("Different: %" PRIu32 "\n", iteration);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    screen_graph_t old_graph = { 0 };
    screen_graph_t new_graph = { 0 };
    old_graph.field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1] = 'O';
    new_graph.field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1] = 'N';
    screen_graph_changes(&old_graph, &new_graph);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that strictly speaking, the address comparisons in the assertions are not reliable if the address is out of bounds of the array (

When run, it crashes with an assertion failure.  The source was in `ob17.c`:

```
Assertion failed: (*buffer >= &local->field[0][0] && *buffer <= &local->field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1]), function screen_graph_interator, file ob17.c, line 30.
Abort trap: 6
```

#### Diagnosis

If you set DISPLAY_ROWS equal to DISPLAY_COLS, you don't get an assertion firing.  With them both at 24, it produces:

```
Different: 576
```

If you swap the arguments DISPLAY_ROWS and DISPLAY_COLS in the calls to `screen_graph_iterator()`, you don't get an assertion firing. With the 24 and 50 values, it produces:

```
Different: 1200
```

The basic problem is that you are accessing the array out of bounds because you've got the expressions for `x` and `y` reversed in the `screen_graph_iterator()` function.  Thus, another solution to the problem uses:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { DISPLAY_ROWS = 24, DISPLAY_COLS = 50 };
//enum { DISPLAY_ROWS = 24, DISPLAY_COLS = 24 };

typedef struct screen_graph
{
    char field[DISPLAY_ROWS][DISPLAY_COLS];
    bool expired;
} screen_graph_t;

static bool screen_graph_interator(screen_graph_t *local, char **buffer,
                uint32_t *iteration, uint32_t start_x, uint32_t start_y,
                uint32_t width, uint32_t height)
{
    int y = start_x + *iteration % width;
    int x = start_y + *iteration / width;
    //int x = start_x + *iteration % width;
    //int y = start_y + *iteration / width;

    if (*iteration > (width * height) - 1)
    {
        *buffer = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    *buffer = &(local->field[x][y]);

    assert(*buffer >= &local->field[0][0] &&
           *buffer <= &local->field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1]);

    (*iteration)++;

    return true;
}

static bool screen_graph_changes(screen_graph_t *old_graph, screen_graph_t *new_graph)
{
    char *old_char = NULL;
    char *new_char = NULL;
    uint32_t iteration = 0;

    while (screen_graph_interator(old_graph, &old_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS))
    //while (screen_graph_interator(old_graph, &old_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_ROWS, DISPLAY_COLS))
    {
        iteration--;
        screen_graph_interator(new_graph, &new_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS);
        //screen_graph_interator(new_graph, &new_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_ROWS, DISPLAY_COLS);
        assert(old_char >= &old_graph->field[0][0] &&
               old_char <= &old_graph->field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1]);
        assert(new_char >= &new_graph->field[0][0] &&
               new_char <= &new_graph->field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1]);

        if (*old_char != *new_char && *new_char != '\0')
        {
            printf("Different: %" PRIu32 "\n", iteration);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    screen_graph_t old_graph = { 0 };
    screen_graph_t new_graph = { 0 };
    old_graph.field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1] = 'O';
    new_graph.field[DISPLAY_ROWS-1][DISPLAY_COLS-1] = 'N';
    screen_graph_changes(&old_graph, &new_graph);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces no assertion failure and the `Different: 1200` output.

---

<sup>*(For 10k users, there was a previous edition of the question: [Can't pass local struct reference to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988815/).  It suffers from the same problem.)*</sup>

Comment: What you have done seems okay, however, as far as I remeber the deleted question had this line `screen_graph_interator(new_graph, &new_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_ROWS, DISPLAY_COLS);`. In this question, it is like this `screen_graph_interator(old_graph, &old_char, &iteration, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS)`. So it is already swapped, therefore you do not need to change `x` and `y`. Or am I still missing something? Because when I print the values I do not get out of bond.

Comment: Are you telling me that when you run the code I show in the first chunk, you don't get an assertion on your platform?  The code in the old question had `while(__screen_graph_interator(local, &local_char, &interation, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS)) {` — I just copied and pasted.  That's the same cols then rows order as in the first block of code, which is my conversion of the code in this question into an MCVE.

Comment: Can you also put the struct of the old question?

Comment: Old question struct: `typedef struct screen_graph {
    char field[DISPLAY_ROWS][DISPLAY_COLS]; 
    bool expired;
} screen_graph_t;` – AFAICS, that's the same as in this question.  Should I include my conversion of the old question code into my answer?  It isn't all that different from what's there already, so I probably won't, but it is tempting.

Comment: I do not want to take your time but if you have time can we move to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129970/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-nanona).